# How to add Google ReCaptcha Properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, validation, recaptcha

I have a PHP contact form that performs validation via AJAX/JSON on the server side and pushes errors to Javascript to print out the errors and alter the HTML/CSS accordingly.

How can I properly implement Google ReCaptcha with AJAX validation?

Here is my code attempt.

**ReCaptcha Snippet:**

```
    //reCAPTCHA validation
    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {

        require('component/recaptcha/src/autoload.php');

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(SECRET_KEY, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());

        $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

          if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
                $errors = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Captcha is Required!'));
                die($output);
          }
    }
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data

// validate the variables ======================================================
    // if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array

    if (empty($_POST['firstName']))
        $errors['firstName'] = 'First Name is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['lastName']))
        $errors['lastName'] = 'Last Name is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['companyName']))
        $errors['companyName'] = 'Company Name is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['companyAddress']))
        $errors['companyAddress'] = 'Company Address is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['city']))
        $errors['city'] = 'City is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['state']))
        $errors['state'] = 'State is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['emailAddress']))
        $errors['emailAddress'] = 'Email Address is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['comment']))
        $errors['comment'] = 'Comment is required.';

        //reCAPTCHA validation
        if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {

            require('component/recaptcha/src/autoload.php');

            $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(SECRET_KEY, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());

            $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

              if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
                    $errors = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Captcha is Required!'));
                    die($output);
              }
        }


// return a response ===========================================================

    // if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
    if ( ! empty($errors)) {

        // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    } else {

        // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message

        // DO ALL YOUR FORM PROCESSING HERE
        // THIS CAN BE WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO (LOGIN, SAVE, UPDATE, WHATEVER)

        // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    }

    // return all our data to an AJAX call
    echo json_encode($data);
```

**Javascript:**

```
// Start
$(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class
        $('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text

        // get the form data
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData = {
            'firstName'                 : $('input[name=firstName]').val(),
            'lastName'              : $('input[name=lastName]').val(),
            'companyName'               : $('input[name=companyName]').val(),
            'companyAddress'                : $('input[name=companyAddress]').val(),
            'city'              : $('input[name=city]').val(),
            'state'                 : $('input[name=state]').val(),
            'emailAddress'          : $('input[name=emailAddress]').val(),
            'comment'   : $('input[name=comment]').val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'formMaster.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data);

                // here we will handle errors and validation messages
                if ( ! data.success) {

                    // handle errors for name ---------------
                    if (data.errors.firstName) {
                        $('#firstName-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#firstName-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.firstName + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for name ---------------
                    if (data.errors.lastName) {
                        $('#lastName-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#lastName-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.lastName + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for name ---------------
                    if (data.errors.companyName) {
                        $('#companyName-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#companyName-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.companyName + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for Company Address ---------------
                    if (data.errors.companyAddress) {
                        $('#companyAddress-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#companyAddress-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.companyAddress + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for Company Address ---------------
                    if (data.errors.city) {
                        $('#city-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#city-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.city + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for Company Address ---------------
                    if (data.errors.state) {
                        $('#state-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#state-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.state + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for Email Address ---------------
                    if (data.errors.emailAddress) {
                        $('#emailAddress-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#emailAddress-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.emailAddress + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for superhero alias ---------------
                    if (data.errors.comment) {
                        $('#comment-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#comment-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.comment + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                } else {

                    // ALL GOOD! just show the success message!
                    $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');

                    // usually after form submission, you'll want to redirect
                    // window.location = '/thank-you'; // redirect a user to another page

                }
            })

            // using the fail promise callback
            .fail(function(data) {

                // show any errors
                // best to remove for production
                console.log(data);
            });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Right now I am just honestly confused on how to get this to work properly. Does the validation answer is obtained by Javascript or PHP or does Javascript pass it on to PHP? If there is an error how can I pass it to Javascript to print the error?

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Master</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- load bootstrap via CDN -->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- load jquery via CDN -->
    <script src="formMaster.js"></script> <!-- load our javascript file -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

    <h1>Contact Form</h1>

    <!-- OUR FORM -->
    <form name="form" id="form" action="formMaster.php" method="POST">

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div id="firstName-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="Henry Pym">
            <!-- errors will go here -->
        </div>

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div id="lastName-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Henry Pym">
            <!-- errors will go here -->
        </div>

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div id="companyName-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="companyName">Company Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="companyName" placeholder="Henry Pym">
            <!-- errors will go here -->
        </div>

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div id="companyAddress-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="companyAddress">Company Address:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="companyAddress" placeholder="Henry Pym">
            <!-- errors will go here -->
        </div>

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div id="city-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="city">City:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="Henry Pym">
            <!-- errors will go here -->
        </div>

        <div id="state-group" class="form-group">
      <label for="state">State</label>
      <select id="statea" name="state" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </div>

        <!-- EMAIL ADDRESS -->
        <div id="emailAddress-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailAddress" placeholder="rudd@avengers.com">
            <!-- errors will go here -->
        </div>

        <!-- COMMENT -->
        <div id="comment-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Ant Man">
            <!-- errors will go here -->
        </div>

                    <div id="recaptcha" class="form-group">
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfKURIUAAAAAO50vlwWZkyK_G2ywqE52NU7YO0S" data-callback="verifyRecaptchaCallback" data-expired-callback="expiredRecaptchaCallback"></div>
                        <input class="form-control d-none" data-recaptcha="true" required data-error="Please complete the Captcha">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>

    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reCaptcha checking is done on the client side, the browser connects to google reCaptcha and checks if the input is from a robot. Then a verification code is returned to the browser.
That verficiation code is the "`g-recaptcha-response`" that is afterwards verified on the server side.

To do the checking on the server side you need to add an aditional field in the ajax call named g-recaptcha-response, with the value returned from the verification.

In the `formData`, you need to include the `g-recaptcha-response` this aditional data field.

```
var formData = {
            'firstName'                 : $('input[name=firstName]').val(),
            'lastName'              : $('input[name=lastName]').val(),
            'companyName'               : $('input[name=companyName]').val(),
            'companyAddress'                : $('input[name=companyAddress]').val(),
            'city'              : $('input[name=city]').val(),
            'state'                 : $('input[name=state]').val(),
            'emailAddress'          : $('input[name=emailAddress]').val(),
            'comment'   : $('input[name=comment]').val(),
            'g-recaptcha-response' : !!! PUT THE VERIFICATION CODE HERE !!!
        };
```

I am not sure which reCaptcha version you are using, hence the way of getting the verification would be different, but here you have the link to check the different alternatives for different version: [reCaptcha V2](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

**Edit I**

In the html file, in `<head>` tag add the recaptcha api:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</script> <!-- load jquery via CDN -->
    <script src="formMaster.js"></script> <!-- load our javascript file -->
```

This will create a `recaptcha` javascript object for linked to the div defined below.

In the html repace you reCaptcha div with this one:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR KEY"></div>
```

Finally in the Javascript use the `recpatcha` object to get the response and add it to the `ajax` call.

```
var formData = {
            'firstName'                 : $('input[name=firstName]').val(),
            'lastName'              : $('input[name=lastName]').val(),
            'companyName'               : $('input[name=companyName]').val(),
            'companyAddress'                : $('input[name=companyAddress]').val(),
            'city'              : $('input[name=city]').val(),
            'state'                 : $('input[name=state]').val(),
            'emailAddress'          : $('input[name=emailAddress]').val(),
            'comment'   : $('input[name=comment]').val(),
            'g-recaptcha-response' : recaptcha.getResponse();
```

};

With these changes you should be getting the `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` in your php.

After that follow the verification steps using this information.

Comment: so would it be like this:  

`if (empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
  $errors['captcha'] = 'Captcha is required.';`

?

Comment: 1) In the ajax call the filed is missing so it will never get to $_POST. 2) In your current code with 'empty' you should get some index not defined or something like that. Use isset instead or combine it with array_key_exists.

Comment: I am using v2 of Google ReCaptcha but what would be the input value for the verification code? `'g-recaptcha-response' : $('input[name=g-recaptcha-response]').val()`

Comment: Can you add the html you are using

Comment: See Edit I for details on setting g-recaptcha in the html page and submitting the verification to the php page.